# Which is better in this sentence, "maintain" or "continue"?

Tags: grammaticality, cloze-test

"If a conversation starts angry, it will almost certainly _____ angry."

This is a question from a cloze quiz, the two options are "maintain" or "continue".

The answer key says that "continue" is the correct answer, but I never heard someone say:"continue adj.", only "continue to be adj." I do however believe that "maintain adj." is a valid structure.

Which is the real correct one, and why?

Comment: You're mistaken. _maintain_ + [n.] is the valid and usually necessary structure.  That said, this is a hard question since the _angry_ is actually being used as an adv. ("in an angry way").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Continue* sounds better *in that sentence* but note that that sentence does not represent idiomatic standard English. Instead it should be something such as *continue in an angry manner*. Or *continue angrily*. The use of the 'flat adverb' *angry* is okay but might not represent standard English. For example, *If a conversation starts angrily, it will almost certainly finish/continue   angrily* represents standard English, whereas *If a conversation starts angry, it will almost certainly finish angry* sounds dialectal/quaint/country.

As for *maintain*, it's incorrect in any of these sentences because *maintain* is used as a transitive verb and so requires an object such as a direct object or a reflexive object (*maintains itself angrily*, although this is most unnatural).

Comment: “...almost certainly ***stay*** angry” is how I’d most likely say it in conversation.  Or maybe *remain*.

Comment: @Jim ... ***end** angry*.

Answer (score 4):

#### The correct one is continue.

The difference is subtle, but 'maintain' means:

> cause or enable (a condition or state of affairs) to continue.

This is wrong because when the conversation *starts* angry, it is not *causing* it to continue angry. You'd say that the people *having* the angry conversation maintained it (without them, it wouldn't continue angry)

Whereas 'continue' is simply:

> persist in an activity or process.

Which is right, because the angry conversation is persisting.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that *maintain* is wrong is that *maintain* is a transitive verb: it must take an object, something which is maintained by a positive action.

*Continue* can be transitive, but it can also be intransitive. Something may simply continue; it doesn't have to *be continued*.

Thus the conversation continues.

The use of an adjective after *continue* rather than an adverb is dialectal.